# dart datetimepicker angular2

Tags: angular, datepicker, dart

I use datetimepicker (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker) in a angular2 template.
However when i click outside the calendar when it is opened I have an uncaught error :

```
 js_helper.dart:1729
 Uncaught wrapException
  @ js_helper.dart:1729call$0
  @ async_patch.dart:561_microtaskLoop
  @ schedule_microtask.dart:41dart._startMicrotaskLoop
  @ schedule_microtask.dart:50dart._AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1
  @ async_patch.dart:54call$0
  @ js_helper.dart:2409eval$1
  @ isolate_helper.dart:462_callInIsolate
  @ isolate_helper.dart:54dart.invokeClosure
  @ js_helper.dart:2409(anonymous function)
  @ js_helper.dart:2429
```

Is there a way to have more details about the error?

Is there a prefered date component to use with angular2 dart ?

Thanks for your help.